# How to fix Bad Authentication data error in twitter API using Rails 4.2.1 ?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twitter-oauth, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Getting **bad authentication data error** after upgrading rails 3.2.13 to rails 4.2.1

```
`ActionView::Template::Error (Bad Authentication data.)`
```

Comment: which social API you are using?

Comment: twitter,Facebook and LinkedIn@rick

Comment: This error comes from twitter

Answer (score 0):

You should update your configuration according to latest upgrade version of Twitter API and you would take look into this issue that same like you and get some more idea on this,

https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/315

Comment: Thank you rick. I've found this link https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/684  almost same problem. I've changed some configuration with have mentioned in that link, But still I can't  find my solution......please help me! Thank you...